# Debugging Streaming API: Receive and monitor all CometD listeners (subscribers)

Tags: streaming-api, cometd, typescript

We have successfully built a couple of integrations to other systems using the Streaming API (mostly Custom Platform Events). However, our "adapter" (written in TypeScript, using [JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/) library) regularly looses connection to some of the channels (usually not all of them). It also looks like connections that are considered "active" by the adapter not always deliver messages. We currently solve this by restarting the container (which also restarts all the subscriptions).

Salesforce provides a couple of options to query platform event subscribers in Apex (or show them in the UI). But these don't help, since they do not include `CometD` subscribers: [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_get_subscribers.htm).

- Is there a way to reliably query all [client listeners](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_concepts_listeners)? This would allow us to monitor (or self-check) that all subscriptions are running?
- Are there better (well maintained?) libraries out there? Any recommendations? We plan to reimplement in Python anyway.
- Does CometD provide a self-check that a connection is healthy and ready to receive?

I appreciate any ideas/suggestions how we can build a resilient, maintainable, self-healing solution.